# Does linux socket "send" function do a hton conversion?

Tags: sockets, endianness

When trying to use TCP/IP socket - "socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)", tcp in this case, does the call to **send** and **recv** do a byte-order conversion automatically ?

Comment: Byte-order conversion of what? You can only send and receive bytes, so there's nothing to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the TCP level, byte ordering only applies to the IPs and ports in the TCP/IP headers, which are established when `connect()`/`accept()` are called.  When working with instances of `sockaddr_in...` structs, the user is responsible for handling byte conversions to/from network byte order as needed.

`send()`/`recv()` simply deal with a socket handle and a raw byte array, so there are no byte order issues when calling them.  However, if the byte array has data that contains multi-byte integers in it, those have to be handled separately by the user as needed.